# Get a single file from a remote mercurial repository

Tags: java, mercurial

Is there a way to programmatically download a single file from a remote Mercurial repository, in Java? I have asked a [very similar question regarding git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642143/get-a-single-file-from-a-remote-git-repository); now I'm hoping I can do something similar with mercurial as well.

1. I prefer a solution which uses as little bandwidth as possible, preferably only downloading that single file. I do not need to browse the repository, I already have the file's path.
2. I am not concerned with the history of the file, I only want its latest version.
3. A solution that only prints the file to the output is great as well, of course - it doesn't really have to save the file to disk, I can do that myself.
4. I prefer a solution which does not depend on other applications (e.g. an installation of a mercurial client on the machine). A Java library which contains a mercurial client implementation itself would be optimal. However, I will happily invoke `hg` if there's no other way.

From what I understand about how Mercurial works - allowing working only against local repositories - this could prove to be problematic; but as I was able to do this with the similar Git SCM I'm hoping there's a solution for Mercurial as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [mercurial wire protocol](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WireProtocol) doesn't have a command for reading a single file from a remote repository. That's why the `hg` command line client can't do this either. The idea is that you should always make a local clone for such things.

However, the various web interfaces for mercurial typically have a way to get at file content. For example, for bitbucket repositories the URL looks like this:

```
http://bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>/raw/<revision>/<filename>
```

For the `hg serve` web interface, the URL looks like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/raw-file/<revision>/<filename>
```

Comment: In addition to that if you need to access private repo's on bitbucket, they have an api: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs

Comment: For the `hg server` web interface, you don't need to know the revision. You can use `tip` instead of the revision number.

Answer (score 3):

The Bitbucket REST API is the tool you want for this.

`https://api.bitbucket/1.0/repositories/{USER}/{REPO-NAME}/raw/tip/{PATH/TO/FILE}`

Example from their [docs](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Source#Source-Overview):

> Instead of getting the file formatted as JSON, you can get the raw
>   file:
>
> $ curl
>   https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/tip/piston/utils.py
>   import time from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed,
>   HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest from
>   django.core....